# Close javascript menu when click on item or lost focus

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to customise a menu I've found on CodePen. [Here's](https://codepen.io/slyka85/pen/LbXYKQ) what I've found.

What I'm trying to do is modify it so that the menu closes after you click on an item, or if you click outside the menu. I've tried various things but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my html:

```
<!-- new hamburger menu be here -->
<div id="menu-main">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
         <div id="hamburger-menu"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
         <!-- hamburger-menu -->
            </div>
    <!-- menu-wrapper -->
            <ul class="menu-list accordion">
                <li id="nav1">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav2">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#about">About the Project</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav3">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#timeline">Timeline</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav4">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#vision">The Vision</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav5">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#where">Where We Are</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav6">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#news">Stay In Touch</a>
                </li>
                <li id="nav7">
                    <a class="menu-link" href="#faq">FAQ</a>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript

```
    $(function() {
  function slideMenu() {
    var activeState = $("#menu-main .menu-list").hasClass("active");
    $("#menu-main .menu-list").animate({left: activeState ? "0%" : "-100%"}, 400);
  }

  $("#menu-wrapper").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#hamburger-menu").toggleClass("open");
    $("#menu-main .menu-list").toggleClass("active");
    slideMenu();

  $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden");
  });

  $(".menu-list").find(".accordion-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("open").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").toggleClass("active");

    $(".menu-list  .accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast").removeClass("open");
    $(".menu-list  .accordion-toggle").not(jQuery(this)).removeClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").removeClass("active");
  });


}); // jQuery load
```

I've tried adding in various classes in this bit as I believe this is what controls the code but no luck:

```
  $(".menu-list").find(".accordion-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("open").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").toggleClass("active");

    $(".menu-list  .accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast").removeClass("open");
    $(".menu-list  .accordion-toggle").not(jQuery(this)).removeClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").removeClass("active");
  });
```

Would love some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check on document click to see if an element has been clicked our the user clicked outside the menu div.

```js
$(function() {
  function slideMenu() {
    var activeState = $("#menu-container .menu-list").hasClass("active");
    $("#menu-container .menu-list").animate({
      left: activeState ? "0%" : "-100%"
    }, 400);
  }
  $("#menu-wrapper").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#hamburger-menu").toggleClass("open");
    $("#menu-container .menu-list").toggleClass("active");
    slideMenu();

    $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden");
  });

  $(".menu-list").find(".accordion-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("open").slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").toggleClass("active");

    $(".menu-list .accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast").removeClass("open");
    $(".menu-list .accordion-toggle").not(jQuery(this)).removeClass("active-tab").find(".menu-link").removeClass("active");
  });


  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    let isLink = jQuery(e.target).is(".accordion-content a");
    let isOutside = jQuery(e.target).closest("#menu-container").length == 0;

    if (isLink || isOutside)
      $("#menu-wrapper").trigger("click");
  })
}); // jQuery load
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background: #FF5722;
}

#menu-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu span {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 9px;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-60px);
}

#menu-wrapper #hamburger-menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-135deg);
}

#menu-container .menu-list .menu-submenu {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#menu-container .menu-list {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) 6px 2px 10px;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  left: -100%;
}

#menu-container .menu-list li.accordion-toggle,
#menu-container .menu-list .menu-login {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: 1px solid #dbdcd2;
}

#menu-container .menu-list li:first-of-type {
  border-top: 0;
}

.accordion-toggle,
.accordion-content {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-toggle a:before,
.accordion-toggle a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #5a5858;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.accordion-toggle a:before {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.accordion-toggle.active-tab {
  background: yellowgreen;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion-toggle a.active:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background: #fff !important;
}

.accordion-toggle a.active:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background: #fff !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-container">
  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="hamburger-menu"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <!-- hamburger-menu -->
  </div>
  <!-- menu-wrapper -->
  <ul class="menu-list accordion">
    <li id="nav1" class="toggle accordion-toggle">
      <span class="icon-plus"></span>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu1</a>
    </li>
    <!-- accordion-toggle -->
    <ul class="menu-submenu accordion-content">
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- menu-submenu accordon-content-->
    <li id="nav2" class="toggle accordion-toggle">
      <span class="icon-plus"></span>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu2</a>
    </li>
    <!-- accordion-toggle -->
    <ul class="menu-submenu accordion-content">
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- menu-submenu accordon-content-->
    <li id="nav3" class="toggle accordion-toggle">
      <span class="icon-plus"></span>
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu3</a>
    </li>
    <!-- accordion-toggle -->
    <ul class="menu-submenu accordion-content">
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a class="head" href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- menu-submenu accordon-content-->
  </ul>
  <!-- menu-list accordion-->
</div>
<!-- menu-container -->
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That worked for clicking outside the menu. Was it meant to work if you click on a menu link or do I need some additional code for that as well?

Comment: It works on both. If you click on submenu item it will hide too.

Comment: Thank you - that worked. Just had to rename a few variables to match my own naming conventions.

Great answer.

Now all I need to do is understand more about JavaScript :)